# Delayed loop function not working properly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

All Imtrying to do is have a loop to iterate over my nav elements, and every second check the data-time to the variable being counted, and change a div to have the text within the list item. Ill already have the list in increasing order so that wont be a issue.

Ive tried 40 different ways to do this and this is my cloest to working solution, it just sets the innerHTML of the div to whitespace and I dont now why.

```
<DOCTYPE! Html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
var navList = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
var y = 0;
for(x = 0; x< 50; x++){
    var timeCheck = navList[y].getAttribute("data-time");
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (timeCheck == x){
            document.getElementById('itemHtml').innerHTML = navList[y].innerHTML;
            y++;
            }
        },1000);
    }
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="nav" data-time="4"> test 1</li>
    <li class="nav" data-time="8"> test 2</li>
    <li class="nav" data-time="14"> test 3</li>
    <li class="nav" data-time="18"> test 4</li>
</ul>
<div>
<h3 id="itemHtml"> placeholder </h3>
<h3 id="test"> placeholder </h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, `navList[y].getAttribute("data-item");` should be `navList[y].getAttribute("data-time");`

Comment: I just relooked over it, and my loop goes to length of the list, and counts, but the times are all beyond that. Changing the length to a arbitrary number still yields nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time your setTimeout executes, the for loop has most likely already gone through all elements. Also it creates a closure, so the x values will not be what you expect it to be. Last but not least,  `setTimeout` executes once after the specified time, you want to use `setInterval`.

Comment: i only need it to execute once after the timeout, since its within a loop and will get called repeatedly

Comment: MJB is right. Add console.log statements in to show where each steps is being called. E.g. inside the loop and inside the setTimeout. http://jsfiddle.net/3pop4g76/ . Firstly you'll see in the console that it loops through and prints out 'inside for loop - iteration 49' before the first setTimeout thing is called. After that it prints out 'inside setTimeout - comparing x:50 to timeCheck:4' 50 times. This is the closure that MJB was referring to.

Comment: I ended up redoing things a bit and used setInterval. Owkring as intended now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is check every second if time has eclipsed up to that date-time of any element? If so use an interval not a set timeout. Also have the loop within each execution of the interval.

```
var navList = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
var y = 0;

var timeCount = 0;
setInterval(function(){ // Create an interval with a function payload.
    timeCount++; // Increment the times hit. This is an an approx of number of seconds
    for(x = 0; x< navList.length; x++){
      var timeCheck = navList[y].getAttribute("data-time");
        console.log('timeCheck: ' + timeCheck + ' timeCount ' + timeCount);
        if(timeCheck == timeCount){ // Have we found a match for this current second?
            console.log('found a match');
            console.log(navList[y].innerHTML);
             document.getElementById('itemHtml').innerHTML = navList[y].innerHTML;
            y++;
        }
    }
}, 1000); // run interval every second.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pop4g76/4/

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using for those interested.

```
<DOCTYPE! Html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
var navList = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
var test = setInterval(function(){
        x++;
        var timeCheck = navList[y].getAttribute("data-time");
        if (timeCheck == x){
            document.getElementById('itemHtml').innerHTML = navList[y].innerHTML;
            y++;
            }
        if(x == 10){clearInterval(test)}
        },1000);
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="nav" data-time="4"> test 1</li>
    <li class="nav" data-time="8"> test 2</li>
    <li class="nav" data-time="14"> test 3</li>
    <li class="nav" data-time="18"> test 4</li>
</ul>
<div>
<h3 id="itemHtml"> placeholder </h3>
<h3 id="test"> placeholder </h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```